# How to mock JSONObject using PowerMock

Tags: junit, easymock, powermock

I need help to mock a JSONObject. Here is what I need to do

The method I need to unit test is

```
public A changeValues (JSONObject jsonObject){
      // look through JSON
      returns A;
}
```

The JSON looks like this

```
{
   "a" : "some value1",
   "b" : {
        "c" : "some value2",
        "d" : "some value3" 
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = createMock(JSONObject.class);
// I am stuck here
expects(json.opt(),"value").anyTimes();
expects(json.optJSONArray,[array]).anyTimes();
```

I dont have a clue how to mock this out. Any help please?

Comment: I have no clue about what you are actually trying to do. Do you want to replace a JSON object by a mock object? Or do you want to mock a method or something? And what are you going to test here?

Comment: I need to unit test the above method. The JSON that is going to be passed to that method is the JSON I put it there. That is the mock JSONObject that needs to be sent to that method. What I am not able to do is create that mock JSONObject

Comment: I don't understand why you want to mock a JSONObject when you want to test the (algorithm? inside the) method. Why not passing a created JSON object at test? What exactly does return A do, that means what is "A"?

Comment: I can definitely send a JSONObject that I can create outside. But going the Powermock/EasyMock way I wanted to use the expects() -> replay & verify on it

Comment: i got the same problem.can you explain how could you create your mock json structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you question, I'm not sure what you're trying to test or really what you issues are, but here as some *EasyMock-101* tips on how it all works. If this is all known to you, I apologise.

---

To create a new mock instance of your class, you use:

```
EasyMock.createMock( JSONObject.class );
```

This has created a new mock object for the JSONObject class. This object is currently in *record* mode. What that means is that any method calls to the mock will be classed as expectations for those method calls and will return null when called.

Then to set up your expectations you use methods like the following:

```
EasyMock.expect( mockJsonObject.opt("a") ).andReturn( "value" ); //Expectation 1

mockJsonObject.testValidity(null) //Expectation 2
EasyMock.expectLastCall();
```

Expectation 1 sets up an expectation that the `opt` method will be called with a parameter `"a"` and then it will return `"value"`

Expectation 2 sets up an expectation that the `testValidity` method will be called with a null object. Because it is a void method, there is no return type and the `expectLastCall()` method is used to mark the method call as an expectation.

You can then use the `EasyMock.replay()` to move your object into replay mode. In this mode any method calls to the mock object will be dealt with by the expectations. If you expected a call to `opt` and then call `opt` the return value you set up will be returned.

Once you've tested what you need to, you should verify that the expectations occurred. This  happens with the `EasyMock.verify()` method.

So a general EasyMock test would look like this:

```
public void thatEasyMockCanMockJsonObject() {
    JSONObject mockJsonObject = EasyMock.createMock(JSONObject.class);
    EasyMock.expect( mockJsonObject.opt( "a" ) ).andReturn( "value" );
    EasyMock.replay( mockJsonObject );

    changeValues( mockJsonObject );

    EasyMock.verify( mockJsonObject );
}
```

---

Some more advanced notes about EasyMock and PowerMock

EasyMock creates it's mocks and mocks the methods by extending the mocked class and overriding the expected methods. For this reason, final, private, package or static methods and classes cannot be mocked with EasyMock. Having said that, JSONObject is none of these things, so it should be possible to mock it with EasyMock.

From the look of the [JavaDoc for JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html), the only reason you would need PowerMock is if you're expecting calls to any of the static methods. If you're not, then you can just use EasyMock.

If you are trying to mock the static method, then PowerMock can be used alongside EasyMock. [Here is the documentation for mocking static methods with PowerMock.](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)  The main points are here:

> ## Mocking static methods
>
> **Quick summary**
>
> 1. Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
> 2. Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
> 3. Use PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to mock all methods of this class.
> 4. Use PowerMock.replay(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to replay mode.
> 5. Use PowerMock.verify(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to verify mode.